# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement [c#]

Tags: c#

```
string userTweet = Console.ReadLine();
userTweet.Length; // returns the length of the password
```

i got the following problem wen i use Length method

"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement [c#]"

Comment: What do you think that code is supposed to do?

Comment: Let's say you enter "Hello" at the Console.  The `UserTweet` variable will then refer to a a string containing "Hello".  At that point, `userTweet.Length` will evaluate to `5`.  What do you think a statement that is effectively `5;` should do?

Comment: The compiler is telling you that you're not DOING anything with the value of "userTweet.Length".  Try printing it, or assigning it to a variable, or using it in an expression.  Do ANYTHING with the value.

Answer (score -2):

How about write the value to the Console?

Console.Writeline(userTweet.Length);